# Redirecting dynamic pages to static pages URL

Tags: seo, apache, htaccess

I decided to convert all my dynamic pages to static pages URLs.
I used to have "/contactUS.php" and now I want the page to be served as "/contact-us".

I used to following rule n .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us contactUS.php [NC,L]
```

It all works fine, but the problem is that I want to prevent entrance to "/contactUS.php" to aviod duplicate content. Of course that adding the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^contactUS.php contact-us [NC,L]
```

creates an infinite loop. What is the best way to achieve the goal, also taking SEO into account?

---

Edit:

This causes an infinite loop:

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us contactUS.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contactUS.php contact-us [NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Joel: see the `RewriteCond` I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-write contact-us as contactUS.php.

Redirect contactUS.php to contact-us.

**Edit:**

Redirects and rewrites are 2 different things. In a redirect, the URL change happens client-side. In a rewrite, the URL change happens entirely server-side. I.e.:

#### Redirect

```
Client: GET /foo
Server: Location: /bar
Client: GET /bar
Server: [/bar]
```

#### Rewrite

```
Client: GET /foo
(Server: /foo --> /bar)
Server: [/bar]
```

So if you set up the above rewrite and redirect rules, the client will always navigate to `/contact-us`, while the server will always serve up `/contactUS.php`.

**Edit2:**

Sorry, I forgot to mention that mod_rewrite applies rewrite rules to internal requests as well as client requests. So you need to add a rewrite condition to the redirect to prevent this:

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ contactUS.php [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=200
RewriteRule ^contactUS.php$ contact-us [R=301]
```

Comment: This causes an infinite loop.:

Comment: When trying RewriteRule ^contact-us contactUS.php [NC,L] , RewriteRule ^contactUS.php contact-us [NC,R=301]

Comment: A redirect is not the same as a rewrite... This will not cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I edited the question with the code that causes the redirection loop (I get "This webpage has a redirect loop." error). What is wrong with that code?